# Error creating a new MonoGame project from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, monogame

I was trying out MonoGame.  I installed the MonoGame add-in, and then created a new Universal Project.  Looked good.

Then I noticed that both the Mac and Android projects created had bad references to a MonoGame assembly.  Some googling revealed this is a known issue, and I was able to remove the bad reference and add the correct one.

But now when I build, I get an error:
Error: /Users/davevr/Documents/github/MonoTestGame/iOS/MonoTestGame.iOS.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets"

I can't find these files anywhere on my machine so I am not sure what the issue is.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the MacOS download? http://www.monogame.net/2016/03/17/monogame-3-5/ It should install those targets to your machine. It might also be possible that the project templates are old and do not correctly reference the right paths.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that the add-in manager for Xamarin Studio would have installed everything needed.  That turned out to be incorrect.  When I downloaded from your link and THEN installed the add-in to Xamarin Studio, it worked correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the `MacOS` download?

http://www.monogame.net/2016/03/17/monogame-3-5/

It should install those targets to your machine. It might also be possible that the project templates are old and do not correctly reference the right paths.